# Altium Error: Multiple top level documents has been used

Tags: pcb-design, altium

I made a project with two PCB boards. There are two top level sheets, and two corresponding PCB boards for each. The *Power supply* board is only providing power to *board A*.
 [image]
I have been getting *Multiple top level documents has been used* error whenever I try to update the PCB boards from the schematics. Is it the wrong way? Is each project file meant for single PCB board?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Altium you can only have one top schematic sheet.

From [Connectivity and Multi-Sheet Design](http://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADOH/Connectivity+and+Multi-Sheet+Design):

> While the project file links the various source documents into a
>   single project, the document-to-document and net connective
>   relationships are defined by information in the documents themselves.
>   A multi-sheet design project is arranged as a hierarchical structure
>   of logical blocks, where each block can be either a schematic sheet or
>   a HDL file (VHDL or Verilog). **At the head of this structure is a
>   single master schematic sheet, more commonly referred to as the
>   project's top sheet**.

You'll have to make another project containing the *Power Supply* schematic and PCB documents.

Comment: what is the purpose of having option to add more PCB files in single project?

Comment: Actually, you can have sheets in a flat design: `If your design is not hierarchical - i.e. the sub schematic sheets are all on the same level, with no sheet symbols referencing further sheets below - the design is a flat one.` So you either have a hierarchical structure with a top sheet or a flat design with only one level of sheets.